# Passagem de parametros de uma lista para sub menu

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu tenho uma lista de usuários que é formada a partir de uma consulta no banco de dados. E os nomes estão em tag `<a>`, que consequentemente ao ser clicado abrirá um submenu, porém quero passar os dados do usuários digitado para este sub menu. Estou utilizando o CodeIgniter.

```
<?php foreach($usuarios as $usuario): ?>
   <tr>
       <th scope="row">
           <a title="Editar" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'menu/usuario/' . $usuario->id . $usuario->nome; ?>"><?php echo $usuario->nome; ?></a>
       </th>
       <td>
           <span><?php echo $usuario->nome; ?></span>
       </td>
       <th>
          <span><?php echo $usuario->id; ?></span>
       </th>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar (por exemplo) jQuery para fazer isso:

```
<a title="Editar" class="campo" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'menu/usuario/' . $usuario->id . $usuario->nome; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $usuario->id; ?>"><?php echo $usuario->nome; ?></a>

...

//jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.campo').click(function(){
        $('.campoid-nosubmenu').value();
        $('.camponome-nosubmenu').value();

        $('.campoid-nosubmenu').value($(this).data("id"));
        $('.camponome-nosubmenu').value($(this).value());
    });
});
```